# How to seal / repair large crack in bumper

Tags: repair, rust, body, bumper

A car was in a collision and the front bumper is dented inward and cracked, I'm guessing up to an inch wide.  Is there a way to either fill the crack with some type of foam? (Sophisticated tools and workbench are not currently available)  If not, then how to at least seal the damage with something that will prevent rust?  I've seen a couple videos that mentioned primer.  Is it as simple as just spraying primer on the affected area?  It's an older vehicle so it doesn't have to look visually pleasing as much as it just has to protect against the elements.

Comment: What is the bumper made of? Metal? Plastic?

Comment: Yes, what is the make/model/year of the vehicle? And a picture would help us tons to help you.

Comment: First of all looks like you will have to take it off. If it is plastic, you can heat it with a heat gun, and bend it back, very close to original shape, unfortunately sometimes the edge of a dent remains, and needs sanding and fillering. To repair cracks you can use a soldering iron, about 100W  (I love it), and a fine aluminium mesh stripes. But some bumpers are made from a weird "non-meltable" plastic.

Comment: Do you have a photo of the damage? That will help us choose the right approach

Comment: Its a 2005 Dodge Grand Caravan.  After looking at it more closely, it appears it is actually some type of plastic.  Is this material susceptible to rust?